# get_users() ORDER BY Not Working

Tags: users

I'm not sure where the problem lies, but the code below just doesn't have the effect of ordering by ID in descending order.

```
$args['role'] = 'subscriber';
$args['orderby'] = 'ID';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';
$args['fields'] = 'all_with_meta';      
$args['meta_query'] = $meta_query; // $meta_query is an array specified someplace above

$my_users = get_users( $args );
```

I'm aware that by default, Wordpress is sorting by 'login' and in ASC order.

Any help here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: below answer should work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the args into an array.

```
$args = array(
    'role'       => 'subscriber',
    'orderby'    => 'ID',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'fields'     => 'all_with_meta',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);

$my_users = get_users( $args );
```

Comment: Same thing... still not the one I expected. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @CarlosOnWeb what do you expect the outcome to be? Doesn't the above solution gets you the user in descending order, orderby ID and if doesn't then check with the `$meta_query`

Comment: Hi @MarutiMohanty, 

I was expecting it to sort by ID in DESC order, but the result is its is sorting by first_name. Very strange.

Comment: Can you update your question defining `$meta_query`

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling with using `get_users()` and sorting the result by the value you want, you might have a look at this topic: [How can I sort get_users() by any value (last_name, user defined fields and more)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206251/how-can-i-sort-get-users-by-any-value-last-name-user-defined-fields-and-more)