# How can I sort get_users() by any value (last_name, user defined fields and more)

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, sort, users

I want to sort the result of `get_users()` by last name, first name, user defined fields or whatever.

How can I achieve this while still using `get_users()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) does not allow you to directly sort by whatever you like, but there are ways around it.

The Codex for `get_users()` says:

> **orderby** - Sort by 'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', 'post_count', 'include', or 'meta_value' (query must also contain a 'meta_key' - see [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)).

`meta_value` is a very powerful way to go here. If you choose it, you have to define the `meta_key` which will then define what to order by.

> **meta_key** - The **meta_key** in the [wp_usermeta table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta) for the **meta_value** to be returned. See [get_userdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Values_in_users_.26_user_meta_table) for the possible meta keys.

`get_userdata()` can [return quite a lot of values,](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata#Notes) possibly enough to order by.

---

**Examples**

So, if you want to order by the users last name for example, use `get_users()` like this:

```
$your_users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=last_name');
```

Order by first name

```
$your_users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=first_name');
```

Order by registration date

```
$your_users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=user_registered');
```

You can of course use `order` to reverse the sorting order

```
// Sorting users by registration date - ascending (standard behaviour)
$your_users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=user_registered');
// Sorting users by registration date - descending (add order=DESC)
$your_users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=user_registered&order=DESC');
```

---

**One step further**

If you want to order by user-defined values, which `get_userdata()` won´t deliver, you can pass another parameter to `get_users()`.

```
$your_users = get_users('fields=all_with_meta');
```

This will result in an array which contains all meta data that is linked to a user. You can then use a custom sort function ([via usort()](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.usort.php)) to order by a specific parameter.

```
$your_users = get_users('fields=all_with_meta');
// very basic comparison...
function compare($a, $b) { return ($a->special > $b->special) ? -1 : 1; }
usort($your_users, 'compare');
```

Comment: `create_function` is a really really bad function to use. It error prone and can have devastating security issues. **NEVER EVER** use it. Use proper closure like `usort( $your_users, function ( $a, $b ) { 'do what you need to do' });`

Comment: Also note, PHP5.5 will reach EOL in 8 months, so never ever try to support versions pre PHP5.3 as you have done. `create_function` is pre PHP 5 IIRC

Comment: Thanks for your note. I improved the code (hopefully) to be more future compatible.

Comment: How could I sort by last_name THEN first_name? This seems impossible to do.

Answer (score 1):

As for the examples:
the mentioned `$your_users = get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=user_registered');` will not work, since user_registered is NOT in user_meta table (therefore no `meta_key` and no `meta_value`) but is in (core) users table, so
`get_users('orderby=user_registered')` will do the job.